# How to get three wins in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is the table:

```
([TeamA],[TeamB],[Win],[date])

('KKR','HYD','KKR',1), 
('KKR','MUM','MUM',2), 
('RCB','HYD','HYD',3), 
('DEL','PUB','PUB',4), 
('RR','PUB','RR',4), 
('RR','DEL','RR',5),
('RCB','CSK','CSK',6),
('RR','CSK','RR',7),
('CSK','MUM','MUM',7),
('MUM','DEL','MUM',8),
('HYD','PUNE','PUNE',9),
('PUB','DEL','DEL',9),
('KKR','DEL','KKR',10),
('KKR','RCB','KKR',10)
```

The required answer should be the teams who are winning 3 in a row and the count. Here for eg RR and MUM are winning once 3 in a row. KKR has 3 wins however if we see the date column it is not 3 in a row hence KKR should not be in the answer and the output should be

```
RR 1
MUM 1
```

Comment: What is your dbms, mysql or sql server?

Comment: `Mysql` or `SQL-server`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using ms sql server 14 fiddle

Comment: *and the count*  The count of what? How many times they have won three-in-a-row? Please [edit] your question to make that clearer.

Comment: the count of 3 wins in a row. In this example it is one in each case

Comment: There should be another column like `date` match played or identity to identify **wins in a row**

Comment: yes the date column is day here. You can consider it as date of a given month

Comment: Add it in sample data

Comment: I don't get it. RR has won on day # 4,5,7. MUM has won on day # 2,7,8. How do they qualify? And I see KKR has only 3 wins. I think your example is screwed up. Please recheck

Comment: because they have won all the 3 consecutive matches they have played, I mean to say whatever the gap in the days are they have won 3 in a row while KKR hasn't

Comment: @SouravA Example is ok. RR won 3 times on row, not 3 time day after day

Comment: KKR has won on day 1, 10, 10..it hasn't lost in between.

Comment: @SouravA Start reading `KKR','MUM','MUM',2), ` It lost with `MUM` so it has win - fail - win - win

Comment: sorry guys, my bad. KKR won 3 and I have corrected it. They have not won 3 in a row so they should not be in the result

Comment: @lad2025 - Ah, I see it now

Comment: One more question is `win - win -win -win` count as 2 hat tricks in row or 1.

Comment: they count as 1, it has to be 6 consecutives or 3, 3 consecutive even after a interval to be counted as 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach (probably it can be done in cleaner way):

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT TeamA AS team FROM #tab
  UNION 
  SELECT TeamB FROM #tab
), cte2 AS 
(
  SELECT c.team
      ,[opponent] = CASE WHEN c.team = t.teamA THEN t.teamB ELSE t.teamA END
      ,t.[win]
      ,t.[day]
      ,[is_winner] = CASE WHEN c.team = t.[win] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM cte c
  JOIN #tab t
    ON c.team = t.teamA
    OR c.team = t.teamB
), cte3 AS
(
  SELECT team, [day], [is_winner],
    r =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY [day])
  FROM cte2
), cte4 AS
(
  SELECT team, Length = MAX(r) - MIN(r) + 1 
  FROM (SELECT team, r
          ,rn=r-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY r)
        FROM cte3
        WHERE is_winner = 1) a
  GROUP BY team, rn
)
SELECT team, SUM(Length/3) AS [Number_of_hat_tricks] 
FROM cte4
WHERE Length >= 3
GROUP BY team;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/409843)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦══════════════════════╗
║ team ║ Number_of_hat_tricks ║
╠══════╬══════════════════════╣
║ MUM  ║                    1 ║
║ RR   ║                    1 ║
╚══════╩══════════════════════╝
```

How it works:

- cte - get all teams
- cte2 - for each team find opponent and check if team wins
- cte3 - add consequitive numbers
- cte4 - calculate length of each island
- final - get the island >= 3 and sum them up (integer division is for counting 6 wins in rows as 2 and 9 in rows as 3,...)

**One final thought:**

Value in in last column has to be unique with the same team:

```
('RR','CSK','RR',7)
('CSK','MUM','MUM',7)

CSK vs RR - 7
CSK vs MUM - 7
```

With current data is impossible to sort it in stable manner. So it should be date with time part:

```
CSK vs RR  2015-12-07 10:00
CSK vs MUM 2015-12-07 21:00       -- now we know that it is the second match
```

Comment: Was going thru your profile on SO. 22.5 K points in a matter of 5 months! You are terrific!

Comment: thanks lad! that was a super quick response and it works very fine. I have wrote a shorter version as I didn't know much concepts you used. I ll share my version

Answer (score 1):

Gaps-and-islands. Calculate the length of each island. Final count is length of island divided by 3 (integer division, discarding fractional part).

I added few more rows (teams `A` and `B`) to illustrate 4 wins of `A`, then 7 wins of `B`, then 4 wins of `A` again, which results in final count of 2 and 2 for both `A` and `B`.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (TeamA varchar(50), TeamB varchar(50), Win varchar(50), dt int);

INSERT INTO @T (TeamA, TeamB, Win, dt) VALUES
('KKR','HYD','KKR',1), 
('KKR','MUM','MUM',2), 
('RCB','HYD','HYD',3), 
('DEL','PUB','PUB',4), 
('RR','PUB','RR',4), 
('RR','DEL','RR',5),
('RCB','CSK','CSK',6),
('RR','CSK','RR',7),
('CSK','MUM','MUM',7),
('MUM','DEL','MUM',8),
('HYD','PUNE','PUNE',9),
('PUB','DEL','DEL',9),
('KKR','DEL','KKR',10),
('KKR','RCB','KKR',10),

('A','B','A',11),
('A','B','A',12),
('A','B','A',13),
('A','B','A',14),

('A','B','B',15),
('A','B','B',16),
('A','B','B',17),
('A','B','B',18),
('A','B','B',19),
('A','B','B',20),
('A','B','B',21),

('A','B','A',22),
('A','B','A',23),
('A','B','A',24),
('A','B','A',25);
```

**Query**

Normally you would have a list of teams in a separate table, here I build it in a `CTE_Teams`. `CTE_Counts` has number of `3-wins-in-a-row` for each consecutive winning streak. As there could be multiple winning streaks for a team (see team `A`), this is summed up further. Teams can be listed in any order in columns `TeamA` and `TeamB`, so in the `WHERE` inside the `CROSS APPLY` there is an `OR` to capture both variants.

So, for each team select only those rows that are relevant for this team. This is done by `CROSS APPLY`.

Then, classic `gaps-and-islands` by numbering rows twice with different partitioning. Difference in row numbers give the groups (islands and gaps).

Filter `WHERE CTE_Teams.Team = CA.Win` leaves only islands of winning teams.

Grouping by `CTE_Teams.Team` gives the size of the island, i.e. number of wins in a row.

Query works in SQL Server 2008.

```
WITH
CTE_Teams
AS
(
    SELECT T.TeamA AS Team
    FROM @T AS T

    UNION -- sic! not ALL

    SELECT T.TeamB AS Team
    FROM @T AS T
)
,CTE_Counts
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_Teams.Team
        --,CA.Win
        --,rn1 - rn2 AS GroupNumber
        --,COUNT(*) AS GroupSize
        ,COUNT(*) / 3 AS FinalCount
    FROM
        CTE_Teams
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT
                T.Win
                ,T.dt
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTE_Teams.Team 
                    ORDER BY T.dt, T.TeamA, T.TeamB) AS rn1
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTE_Teams.Team, T.Win 
                    ORDER BY T.dt, T.TeamA, T.TeamB) AS rn2
            FROM @T AS T
            WHERE
                T.TeamA = CTE_Teams.Team
                OR T.TeamB = CTE_Teams.Team
        ) AS CA
    WHERE
        CTE_Teams.Team = CA.Win
    GROUP BY
        CTE_Teams.Team
        ,CA.Win
        ,rn1 - rn2
    HAVING COUNT(*) / 3 > 0
)
SELECT
    CTE_Counts.Team
    ,SUM(CTE_Counts.FinalCount) AS FinalCount
FROM CTE_Counts
GROUP BY CTE_Counts.Team
ORDER BY CTE_Counts.Team;
```

**Result**

```
+------+------------+
| Team | FinalCount |
+------+------------+
| A    |          2 |
| B    |          2 |
| MUM  |          1 |
| RR   |          1 |
+------+------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d6954dd72e53b9015d2a6e6546058f8/14/0)

Answer (score 1):

One more possible way of solving this without using CTE:

```
create table #a
(
teama varchar(10), teamb varchar(10), win varchar(10), dat int)

insert into #a
values
('KKR','HYD','KKR',1), 
('KKR','MUM','MUM',2), 
('RCB','HYD','HYD',3), 
('DEL','PUB','PUB',4), 
('RR','PUB','RR',4), 
('RR','DEL','RR',5),
('RCB','CSK','CSK',6),
('RR','CSK','RR',7),
('CSK','MUM','MUM',7),
('MUM','DEL','MUM',8),
('HYD','PUNE','PUNE',9),
('PUB','DEL','DEL',9),
('KKR','DEL','KKR',10),
('KKR','RCB','KKR',10);

select 
team, 
win,
row_number() over (partition by team order by dat) matchnum
into #res
  from 
    (
    select teamA team, case when teamA = win then 1 else 0 end as win, dat
    from #a 
    union all
    select teamB team, case when teamB = win then 1 else 0 end , dat
    from #a 
    )A 
order by team,dat


select 
    match1.team, count(*)/3 + 1 cntHatricks
from #res match1 join #res match2 
    on match1.team = match2.team and match2.matchnum = match1.matchnum+1
join #res match3 on match1.team = match3.team and match3.matchnum = match1.matchnum+2
where 
    match1.win = 1 and match2.win = 1 and match3.win = 1            
    group by match1.team
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+------+-------------+
| Team | cntHatricks |
+------+-------------+
| MUM  |          1  |
| RR   |          1  |
+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

try this simple query

```
select  tm,sum(case when win=tm  then 1 else 0 end)/3 hattrick from @a a
inner join (select teama tm from @a union select teamb from @a) t on a.win=t.tm 
group by tm
having count(distinct dat)>2
```

data

```
declare @a table 
(teama varchar(10), teamb varchar(10), win varchar(10), dat int)
insert into @a
values
('KKR','HYD','KKR',1), 
('KKR','MUM','MUM',2), 
('RCB','HYD','HYD',3), 
('DEL','PUB','PUB',4), 
('RR','PUB','RR',4), 
('RR','DEL','RR',5),
('RCB','CSK','CSK',6),
('RR','CSK','RR',7),
('CSK','MUM','MUM',7),
('MUM','DEL','MUM',8),
('HYD','PUNE','PUNE',9),
('PUB','DEL','DEL',9),
('KKR','DEL','KKR',10),
('KKR','RCB','KKR',10)
```

;

Answer (score 0):

with abc as (select *,case teama when win then teamb else teama end lose from ipl)
   (select b.win,count(hatrick)/3 as number 
   from ipl b join 
       (select a.win,count(*) as hatrick 
        from ipl a join ipl b on a.win=b.win
        where a.day < b.day and a.day > all 
            (select abc.day
            FROM abc join ipl a on a.win=abc.lose
            WHERE abc.lose=b.win and  abc.day < b.day)
            group by a.win) d
            on b.win=d.win
            where hatrick>=3 group by b.win)

Hey Guys, I have used this version. Let me know if there is any glitch in this